# The first character in both string won't swap in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 101
void swap(char *a, char *b);

int main(void) {
    char string1[SIZE];
    char string2[SIZE];
    printf("please enter string 1 :");
    scanf("%s", string1);

    printf("please enter string 2 :");
    scanf("%s", string2);

    swap(string1, string2);

    printf("string 1 is %s, string 2 is %s\n", string2, string1);
}

void swap(char *a, char *b) {    
    int i;
    char temp[101];
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        temp[i] = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp[i];
    }
}
```

When I give inputs to both `string1` and `string2` lets say `"yes"` and `"hello"`, it will print `string1` is `yello` and `string2` is `hes`. I've tried to modify by changing `*b` to `*[b+1]` and `*a` to `*[a+1]` and it gets the first character to work but now the second character won't swap.

EDIT

Also I've tried another function but the problem is still there.

```
void swap(char* a, char* b)
{
    char temp;
     temp=*a;
     *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
    a++;
    b++;
}
```

Comment: you need to increment a and b inside for

Comment: Please ask a coherent question. Your title says: "first character in both string won't swap." Yet the **first characters are the only ones that are swapped!** Please read the help page on [mcve].

Comment: Also you're printing `string2` as the **string 1** and vice versa!

Comment: All you're doing is swapping the first character, then you're printing the strings in reverse order (string2 followed by string1).  So it *looks* like everything but the first character has been swapped, but in fact it's the exact opposite.  You've been given a solution but your other bug (the backwards printf) prevented you from recognizing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `swap` function is wrong:

Here is the corrected version:

```
void swap(char* a, char* b)
{
  int i; char temp;
  for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
  {
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = temp;
  }
}
```

---

- you don't need a `temp` array, just one `char` is enough for the temporary.
- you need to access the different chars of the input `a` and `b`, and not only the first one.

---

BTW: here is a better version of `swap` where you pass the size as parameter:

```
void swap(char* a, char* b, int size)
{
  int i; char temp;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've tried the corrected version but it won't swap the string...

Comment: Another way to control it would be to swap up to and including the terminating null character.

Comment: @k'hng Are you sure?  You're printing string2, string1 - try reversing them in your `printf`.

Comment: @k'hng yes it does, comment out the call to `swap` in your program and see what happens.

Comment: Yup finally get it to work. I've done so by reversing the string 1 and string 2 in my scanf. What a mistake I've made..Thank Tom and Michael for being such a great help...

Comment: If its not too much trouble can you guys please explain to me why the other function will give me the same problem as well? and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @k'hng The other function you posted is just swapping the first character.  If you want to swap the entire strings, you need to loop over each pair of characters, not just the first pair.  Try working it out on paper.  Follow the code and see what it does.  It really doesn't get much simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually only the first characters of your strings is swapped(which makes sense as mentioned in other answers), you don't see this because you change the order of printing with

```
printf("string 1 is %s, string 2 is %s\n", string2, string1);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here you are always just swapping the first character since you `a` and `b` always point to first element.

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    temp[i]= *a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp[i];
}
```

you can use array subscript

```
int i; char temp;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  temp = a[i];
  a[i] = b[i];
  b[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parentheses like `*(a+1)` instead of bracket `*[b+1]`. In your code
change the following

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
     temp[i]= *a;
     *a=*b;
     *b=temp[i];
}
```

with

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
     temp[i] = *(a+i);
     *(a+i) = *(b+i);
     *(b+i) = temp[i];
}
```

Final code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 101
void swap(char* a, char* b);

int main(void)
{
    char string1[SIZE]; char string2[SIZE];
    printf("please enter string 1 :");
    scanf("%s",string1);

    printf("please enter string 2 :");
    scanf("%s",string2);

    swap(string1, string2);

    printf("string 1 is %s, string 2 is %s\n",string1,string2);
    return 0;
}

void swap(char* a, char* b)
{    
   int i; char temp[101];
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = *(a+i);
        *(a+i) = *(b+i);
        *(b+i) = temp[i];
    }
}
```

[image: Output is here]

Comment: Why use `*(a+i)` instead of `a[i]`?

Comment: `a[i]` is actually resolved to *(a+i). In array declaration `array[n]`, variable name `array` stores the base address. When we use `array[i]`, it first add `number of bytes * i` and add it to base address to get actual address at which value is stored.

Comment: Of course `*(a+i)` and `a[i]` are equivalent in this case, but `a[i]` is much simpler to read and understand. Btw in array declaration `int array[n];`, `array` is not a variable, it is the name of the array. in `array[i]`, `array` decays into a pointer to the first entry of the array, whose value is the base address of the array.

Comment: Your explanation *You have to use parentheses instead of bracket.* is misleading: both array notations can be used interchangeably, but the OP uses none, which **is** the problem.

Comment: OK, I agree. I was trying to say In `int array[n]`, `array` works as identifier like in case of declaration of a simple variable.

Comment: I know what you were trying to say, but your wording would not help people confused about pointers and arrays. To make things worse, as a function argument definition, `int array[n]` indeed defines `array` as a pointer. The details of pointer arithmetic implementation are beyond the scope of this simple question, although they might help understand how pionters and arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you print the strings in the wrong order
- you only swap the first character, and you do this `SIZE` times. `SIZE` is odd so you see it swapped, the previous bug makes it look like the other characters were swapped. If `SIZE` were even, you would not swap anything and the previous bug would let you erroneously believe everything is fine...

Less important, but worth mentioning:

- you do not check the return values of `scanf()`
- you do not return `0` at the end of `main()`.

Here is a corrected and improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 101

void swap(char *a, char *b, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char temp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = temp;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char string1[SIZE];
    char string2[SIZE];

    printf("please enter string 1 :");
    if (scanf("%s", string1) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("please enter string 2 :");
    if (scanf("%s", string2) != 1)
        return 1;

    swap(string1, string2, SIZE);

    printf("string 1 is %s, string 2 is %s\n", string1, string2);
    return 0;
}
```